# Firebase Analytics - Can not logging only custom events

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

We're trying to use firebase analytics in our ios app.

Default events seems to be logged with no problem.

> `5.1.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event params: screen_view (_vs)`

However, only custom event is not logged with this log below.

> `5.1.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS025018] Event not logged. Call +[FIRApp configure]: custom_event_name`

I think configurating is following the document.
We have two different project's plist for each targets to setting up development environment to use different Firebase projects based on build type or target.

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: googleServiceInfoPlist, ofType: "plist"),
  let opts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: path) else {
  fatalError("Couldn't load config file")
}
FirebaseApp.configure(options: opts)
```

I guessed multiple plists causes this problem at first, but there was no changes with a `GoogleService-Info.plist` and calling `FirebaseApp.configure()` .

Sending event's func is just like this.

```
private func sendToFirebase(_ event: Trackable) {
 Analytics.logEvent(event.name, parameters: event.properties)
}
```

What are the possible causes?

Thank you.

Comment: why you use this FirebaseApp.configure(options: opts) ,as firebase documentation it's use as 
FirebaseApp.configure()

Comment: Because I need to switch plist based on target.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/?authuser=0#supporting_different_environments
@Yatendra

Answer (score 4):

I solved by myself.

This is caused by setting up cocoapods for embedded framework.

My Podfile was like below,

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
swift_version = '4.1'
use_frameworks!

target 'AppCore' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

  target 'App' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

`AppCore` is embedded framework.

`pod 'Firebase/xxx'` should be targeted to main app, not embedded framework.

I did:

- Eliminate dependency of Firebase from embedded framework
- Fixed podfile not targeting to embedded framework

then tracked customs events correctly.

Comment: I'm looking for the solutions like this, but I couldn't fully understand what you wrote. Could you explain more about this? I wonder the final version of `Podfile` you're using which solves this issue.

Comment: I solved this issue by moving `pod 'Firebase/Core'` to main target, not embedded framework target.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We need to use Firebase dependency in both targets. I did a workaround that I place `Firebase/Core` to the `App` target and use `inherit! :search_paths` in `AppCore` target. (And `App` target includes `AppCore` target which is opposite to your Podfile above)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with manually adding the Firebase Analytics SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this in my project, turns out I forgot to add `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate` in the `@main` struct. Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

```
@main
struct YourApp: App {
  // register app delegate for Firebase setup
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate // here

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      NavigationView {
        ContentView()
      }
    }
  }
}
```